# Не могу подключить css в php

Tags: php, html, css

Не могу соединить `css` внутри файла `index.php`,
точнее внутри функции. Помогите пожалуйста.

Файл index.php

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ) $page = 'home';
else {

    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    if ( !preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,15}$/', $page) ) exit('error url');
}

session_start();

if ( file_exists('all/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'all/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSON['ulogin'] == 1 and file_exists('auth/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'auth/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSON['ulogin'] != 1 and file_exists('guest/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'guest/'.$page.'.php';

else exit('Страница 404');


function top( $title ) {

header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>'.$title.'</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="menu">
<a href="/">Главная</a>
<a href="/login">Вход</a>
<a href="/register">Регистрация</a>
</div>


<div class="content">
<div class="block">';
}

function bottom() {

echo '
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>';
}

?>
```

Вот файл  который функция работает(login.php)

```
<? top('Вход') ?>

<? bottom() ?>
```

а это css

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0}


a {text-decoration: none}

.wrapper, .content, .menu, body, html {
    height: 100%;
}




.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}



.content {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 40px;
    background: #FCFCFD;
}


.block {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #EEEFF2;



}



.menu {
    width: 200px;
    background: #464E78;
}



.menu a {
    display:
    block; color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

Comment: Что это такое и где тут css?

Comment: прошу прошение я на этом сайте первый раз, почему то код написанной мной отображается как страница(генерируется)

Comment: как тут можно вставить свой код? просто копй пес?

Comment: Копируешь код в текстовое поле, выделяешь и жмешь "Пример кода" (Ctrl+K)

Comment: Так а в итоге то что, элементы на странице отображаются, а css не подключается или какие симптомы? Если да, то где лежит css файл? Если в корне, то <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> замени на <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />

Comment: элементы меню(Главная, Вход) отображаются, а вот css то есть там цвет фон не чего не отображается

Comment: где находятся стили относительно корня сайта?

Comment: в Open Servere, все файлы в одном папке: 
.htaccess,
index.php,
style.css

Comment: извините, а тут можно как то файлы скинуть?

Comment: можно закинуть в какую-нибудь файло-помойку типа яндекс диска и прикрепить ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Это index.php можете его тоже тестировать и выравнивать или как можно тестировать можете сказать?
 пожалуйста

```
<?php

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ) $page = 'home';
else {

    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    if ( !preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,15}$/', $page) ) exit('error url');
}

session_start();

if ( file_exists('all/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'all/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSON['ulogin'] == 1 and file_exists('auth/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'auth/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( $_SESSON['ulogin'] != 1 and file_exists('guest/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'guest/'.$page.'.php';

else exit('Страница 404');


function top( $title ) {

header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>'.$title.'</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="menu">
<a href="/">Главная</a>
<a href="/login">Вход</a>
<a href="/register">Регистрация</a>
</div>


<div class="content">
<div class="block">';
}

function bottom() {

echo '
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Да вроде все норм, могу предположить, что проблема в .htaccess Если предположение, что он перенаправляет все запросы на индексный файл невзирая на расширение.

Comment: Вот содержание  .htaccess?
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: собственно это и предполагал, добавлю к своему ответу то что должно быть в htaccess

Comment: спасибо вам добрый человек, ответ ваш где можно увидеть? на вверху где сообщение?

Comment: а все все ) видел

Answer (score -3):

Код очень странный, сложно понять где лишние знаки, а где реально имеющиеся, по этому напишу как я тестил. В одном каталоге (на одном уровне) лежат index.php и style.css, все нормально работает:

**index.php**

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

function top( $title )
{
    echo <<<HTML
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>{$title}</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <a href="/">Главная</a>
                        <a href="/login">Вход</a>
                        <a href="/register">Регистрация</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="block">
HTML;
}

function bottom()
{
    echo <<<HTML
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
HTML;
}

top('Меню');
bottom();
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```